# How do I remove this cabinet drawer?

Tags: cabinets, drawers

I have a bathroom cabinet drawer that needs to be removed so I can repair the bottom. I can't figure out how to remove it. What do I push or pull to get it out?

This is the drawer fully extended:
[image]

A close up, fully extended:
[image]

A close up, pushed in a bit. Note the pointy black plastic piece is now inside the slide. Note also the button at the left edge of the T. No amount of pushing in the button while sliding the drawer in and out unlatched it:
[image]

The pointy thing does go up and down, but I couldn't get anything to release by moving it.

Comment: one pushes up, the other goes down, they are very uncooperative so try one at a time until you feel it disengage.

Comment: Is there any indication the clips are broken?  Any jagged edges or thin bits?  You might be up for replacement rails.

Comment: When you do figure it out, write yourself (or the next person)  a reminder note on the side or inside of the drawer for next time.

Comment: Any update? Still hunting?

Comment: Still struggling. It seems that the pointy thing is lower on the left hand side of the drawer than it is on the right, and that's the case on all three drawers. Complicating the situation is that the drawer pulls out right next to the wall, which makes it hard to get my fingers in there. But neither pushing up nor down on the pointy thing on either side, or both sides simultaneously, seems to help.

Answer (score 9):

Push up on the pointy thing and pull on the drawer.  [see details here](https://www.accuride.com/blog/slideology/slideology-101-art-disconnect/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. None of the described disconnect types match my drawer, neither pushing up or down seem to do it, on any of the drawers.

Comment: Typically one pushes up and the other goes down. Try retracting the drawer in the cabinet a few inches, move the levers and tug the drawer out. If that doesn't work then reverse which lever went up and which one went down and tug again the same way. It will not damage the glide, it just gives it that little extra "nudge".

Comment: I have those rails, they are good at keeping the drawer in place and suck at removing. Push Down on the level and pull. It will work, though it will take some trying.